# Is every closed ball (or open ball) in the Eucledean Space $R^n$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

I am solving a problem and I need to use this fact:

Every closed ball (or open) in  the Eucledean Space $R^n$ convex?

Hoever, I am not sure if it is true or not. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: What you would need to show is that if $d(x,x_0)\leq \epsilon,$ then for every $y$ on the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$, $d(y,x_0)\leq \epsilon$. Is this true?

Comment: @Kevin Carlson: What I wanted to show is if you pick any two points $x$ and $y$ inside the ball, then the line segment joining those two points lie inside the ball as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are in $B(z,r)$. Then, for $\theta\in[0,1]$,
$$
|\theta x+(1-\theta)y-z|=|\theta(x-z)+(1-\theta)(y-z)|\\
\leq\theta|x-z|+(1-\theta)|y-z|<\theta r+(1-\theta)r=r
$$
so that $\theta x+(1-\theta)y$ is also in $B(z,r)$. The case for the closed ball is similar (the only difference is that the last inequality above will be weak.)