Prove that the intersection of two closed balls is a convex set

Given two arbitrary vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}{^n} ,(v\neq w)$ and a radius $r>\frac{1}{2}\left\| v-w \right\|$, prove that $\overline{B}_r(v)\cap\overline{B}_r(w)$ is a convex set.

I´ve been trying to prove this for a lot of time but I just don´t get anywhere. I´ve been trying with the triangle inequality but I don´t get any results. One thing I noticed is that the condition of the radius ($r>\frac{1}{2}\left\| v-w \right\|$) doesn´t help at all, is just there so that $\overline{B}_r(v)\cap\overline{B}_r(w)\neq\emptyset$ (It´s just my intuiton, maybe I´m wrong).
PD: English isn´t my native language, so sorry for any grammar mistakes
Edit: Regarding @Anne Bauval´s comment, I don´t think this question is similar to the one attached in the comment because that question is for any type of convex set . The answer to this one implies to first prove that a closed ball is a convex set and then use the principle that the intersection of two convex sets is a convex set. No answer in the link attached shows the proof of a closed ball being convex.

@hff1 Any intersection, not just the finite ones.

As for the convexity of balls (which, if needed, should have been a separate question), see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936637

Take two points $x,y\in\overline{B}_r(v)\cap\overline{B}_r(w) $ and some $\lambda \in [0,1] $. Then: $$||\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-v|| = ||\lambda(x-v)+(1-\lambda)(y-v)||\leq \lambda ||x-v|| + (1-\lambda)||y-v||\leq\lambda r+(1-\lambda)r =r. $$ So $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in\overline{B}_r(v)$. The same argument shows $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in\overline{B}_r(w)$. And we conclude $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in\overline{B}_r(v)\cap \overline{B}_r(w)$. So $\overline{B}_r(v)\cap \overline{B}_r(w)$ is convex.
Notice that we essentially showed that a ball in a normed space is convex.

Good answer, but note that you showed two things: first that a ball in a normed space is convex, and then, a particular case of the general principle that the intersection of convex sets is convex.
